# GLSL vectors questions

Tags: opengl, glsl

In OpenGL GLSL syntax, is there any difference between the components of a vector?
I mean, for a given vec3, the xyzw, rgba and stpq, have any real differences between them or is just a helper?
So if I set a color value into a vec3, I assume that though for making it clear to read I would use the rgba, xyzw would give the same values, right?

Comment: See GLSL spec section 5.5 http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf The OpenGL and GLSL specification documents are actually very readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I am not certain how it is implemented, but I think it might be some sort of a union, in which case writing to one and reading from the other is not guaranteed to work.

EDIT: The above comment holds for unions in general (C/C++), however the case in GLSL might be different. The link: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Types#Swizzling states that:

"You can use xyzw, rgba (for colors), or stpq (for texture coordinates). These three sets have no actual difference; they're just syntactic sugar."

So as @tito mentioned in the comment, it is just syntatic sugar, and can be mixed. (although not mixed in a single call, for instance xyga is not valid)

Comment: Absolutely. Theses will give you the same values, you can switch from one notation to another without issues. It just give you a tips about what type of value you wanted to control.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is just a helper so

```
vec.xyzw = vec.rgba = vec.stpq
```

and so on. You can use which ever set you want you just can not mix the set like

```
vec3 pos;
pos.xgb = vec3(1,1,1);  // not valid do to mixing the sets
```

Answer (score 0):

From Kronos.org - Data Type (GLSL):

> You can use xyzw, rgba (for colors), or stpq (for texture coordinates). These three sets have no actual difference; they're just syntactic sugar. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Vectors

It is one of the many convenient features offered by GLSL to make vectors manipulation more flexible, like [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling).